# find a problem into mongodb cpu usage in mongodb atlass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

Since a few days ago, resource usage of the database has increased a lot when we don't have a new query is added to the system
I am asking for help on how to solve the problem

[image]

And, I received the following alert:

```
System: CPU (Steal) % has gone above 50
Unsustainable CPU usage levels are being throttled by the cloud provider. Ensure no index is missing and scale-up.
```

I do not know what additional explanation I can give

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please have a look at [ask] and [help] on how to provide us with meaningful data in your question. Adding the configuration file of your database instance might help. But please do have a look at the recommend links. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information. The community would have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is

```
System: CPU (Steal) % has gone above 50
```

CPU Steal happens when the VM does not get its full allotment of CPU cycles from the VM host.

This can be because the child VMs together were using more that is available, or your instance has exhausted its CPU credits and is being throttled.

There is a little more available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34195206/2282634

Datadog has a discussion about ec2 steal: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/understanding-aws-stolen-cpu-and-how-it-affects-your-apps/

You might try increasing the size of the instance to get more CPU cycles.